# Pin Keep Reminder to notification shade?

Tags: google-keep

How do I pin my todo list (which is a reminder so that it appears on my calender) from keep to the notification shade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no native way in Android to do it unless the app itself implements it. However, some hacky ways to achieve it-

1. Using apps - [Boomerang Notifications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=comsc.cardiff.ac.uk.boomerang) and [Pin Notifications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=yashwant.com.pinnotification&hl=en)
2. Using Tasker - https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/4orcfg/make_notification_persistent/d5h8ln9/
3. Xposed Module - https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/4-1-pinnotif-pin-notifications-to-avoid-t2765095 (Not updated in a while, will be incompatible with latest versions of Android)